# pyparsing grammer to extract portions of Python snippet

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a Python snippets which look like the following:

```
fn = HiveExecOperator(
        task_id="abc",
        hql="abc.hql",
        dq_sql=DQCheck("pqr")
        .is_within_range(
            "COUNT(DISTINCT billing_association_type)",
            "type_cnts",
            lower=1.0,
            upper=float("inf"),
        )
        .build(),
        dag=main_dag,
    )
```

I would like to define a grammar which lets me look at the key-value pair in the parameter list of the function `HiveExecOperator` without breaking down the nested ones. For example - I am interested in getting back a list:

```
[task_id="abc", 
 hql="abc.hql",
 ...
 dq_sql=DQCheck("pqr")
        .is_within_range(
            "COUNT(DISTINCT billing_association_type)",
            "type_cnts",
            lower=1.0,
            upper=float("inf"),
        )
        .build(),
...]
```

I tried doing the following:

```
assignment = variable + '=' + "HiveExecOperator" + nestedExpr('(', ')').setParseAction(lambda x: print(x))

parameters.transformString(python_snippet)
```

Output from `setParseAction` is:

```
['fn', '=', 'HiveExecOperator(']
['task_id', '=', '"abc",']
['hql', '=', '"abc.hql",']
['dq_sql', '=', 'DQCheck("stage.billing_associations")']
['lower', '=', '1.0,']
['upper', '=', 'float("inf"),']
...
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by mkrieger1, you can use the `ast` built-in Python library.

In Python 3.9 (or later), there is the [`ast.unparse`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html#ast.unparse) function that can turn the `ast.Node` into a string.

```py
import ast

mycode = """\
fn = HiveExecOperator(
        task_id="abc",
        hql="abc.hql",
        dq_sql=DQCheck("pqr")
        .is_within_range(
            "COUNT(DISTINCT billing_association_type)",
            "type_cnts",
            lower=1.0,
            upper=float("inf"),
        )
        .build(),
        dag=main_dag,
    )
"""

root = ast.parse(mycode)
calls = [n for n in ast.walk(root) if isinstance(n, ast.Call)]
first_call = calls[0]
target_list = [(k.arg, ast.unparse(k.value)) for k in first_call.keywords]
print(target_list)
```

which gives

```
[
   ('task_id', "'abc'"),
   ('hql', "'abc.hql'"),
   ('dq_sql', "DQCheck('pqr').is_within_range('COUNT(DISTINCT billing_association_type)', 'type_cnts', lower=1.0, upper=float('inf')).build()"),
   ('dag', 'main_dag')
]
```